# Axios Error on Web Development Server in Backend

Tags: axios, backend, web-development-server

I am getting Axios error when I am running the program .

My index.js file : `

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const productRoute = require("./routes/product");
const orderRoute = require("./routes/order");
const cartRoute = require("./routes/cart");
const stripeRoute = require("./routes/stripe");
const cors = require("cors");


dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL
    ).then(()=>console.log("DBConnected")).catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err);
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth" , authRoute);
app.use("/api/users" , userRoute);
app.use("/api/products" , productRoute);
app.use("/api/orders" , orderRoute);
app.use("/api/carts" , cartRoute);
app.use("/api/checkout" , stripeRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000 , () =>
{
    console.log("Backend Server is Running")
});    `
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAUoi.png)My PayNow.jsx file code :

```
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import {useState , useEffect} from "react" ;
import axios from "axios";


const KEY = "pk_test_51OGIIPSJK6QkkFx9Kb9L26vcjkdzuRWqIHEEHRCdVw7fhSn8vH6OdO2tSiiUkgja5WP80jhw3spS6S2dNVk177ZM00Ds9BBHRs"
const PayNow = () =>{

  const [stripeToken , setStripeToken] = useState(null)

  

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
       const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment" , {
        tokenId : stripeToken.id,
        amount  :2000,
       });
       console.log(res.data);
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  },[stripeToken]);

  return (
    <div style ={{
      height : "100vh",
      display : "flex",
      alignItems : " center",
      justifyContent : " center"
    }}
    >
      <StripeCheckout name="#Ashi Shop"
       image ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6up3tF8dy_XdVLYcB6dWwjaxV0bu4YO7WOqmN9LY&s" 
       billingAddress
       shippingAddress
       description= " Your total is INR 20"
       amount = {2000}
       token= {onToken}
       stripeKey = {KEY}
       >

      <button style = {{
        border : "none",
        width:120,
        borderRadius : 5 ,
        padding : "20px",
        backgroundColor : " black",
        color : "white"
      
      }}>
        Pay Now
      </button>
      </StripeCheckout>
      
    </div>

  )
}
export default PayNow;
```

`My stripe.js file code :`

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment" , (req,res)=>{
    stripe.charges.create({
        source : req.body.tokenId,
        amount : req.body.amount,
        currency:"INR"
    }, (stripeErr , stripeRes)=>{
        if(stripeErr){
            res.status(502).json(stripeErr);
        }else{
            res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
        }
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

I am expecting that my data is loaded to backend sever that is on Stripe Website when I click on PayNow through localhost:3000/pay and enter the valid details that it should complete the backend work properly.

Comment: It would appear that this line of code is executing: `res.status(502).json(stripeErr);`  So, what is `stripeErr`?  What information does it contain?